# How do I get TypeProviders to work on Xamarin/Monodevelop

Tags: f#, xamarin, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, type-providers

I want to play around with type providers in F# on mono but I can't get it to work in xamarin studio.

I see that the error is that the namespace TypeProviders is not defined, but where do I find it in monodevelop?

What I did was created the tutorial project for F# and commented out the OData sample. After I commented out that sample I added the `System.Data.Services.Client`, but I can't find `Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders`.

Comment: It's not supported yet--not in Mono.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, are you sure about this? See this tweet: https://twitter.com/tomaspetricek/status/285378570048634880. The TypeProviders dll are build in the latest version of mono.

Comment: Ah--then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5):

There are some issues with certain type providers, mainly due to them calling external tools which have a different location in Mono.  Thats certainly true of the WSDL provider and the EDMX provider, both have counterparts in Mono but in different locations.  If you could raise issues [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues) then they can be addressed by anyone working on the open source compiler and tools.

Comment: Should I raise issues with project templates there as well? I think the f# tutorial project template should work right of the box to lower the barrier for everyone who wants to try out F# on mono.

Comment: As for the template projects, thats an issue with the F# binding, you should raise then here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues?labels=MonoDevelop&sort=updated&state=open

Comment: Where would one find the source code for these providers?   I do not think these providers have been open sourced.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza They are in the source tree here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProvidersImpl.fs  You can see where the svcutil is used for the binding.